# Install DataStax DevCenter on MAC

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

does anyone know how to install DataStax DevCenter on Mac?

I am taking a NoSQL class where we were asked to install Cassandra. All the windows users installed Cassandra and DevCenter. I did install Cassandra on my computer using HomeBrew, but I was having problem running cqlch commands due file path not found. I was thinking if I could install DataStax DevCenter, it would be easier for me to run command. Can anyone advise please?

Regarding the error message I received of path not found, below is an example of what I encountered:

```
cqlsh:stockwatcher> source '/Users/UserName/Downloads/Stockwatcher/labs/lab6b/insertusers.cql';

Could not open '/Users/UserName/Downloads/Stockwatcher/labs/lab6b/insertusers.cql': [Errno 2] 
No such file or directory: '/Users/UserName/Downloads/Stockwatcher/labs/lab6b/insertusers.cql'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this link to download:

https://academy.datastax.com/downloads#devCenter

OR

https://academy.datastax.com/all-downloads

"cqlch commands due file path not found" --> Please go to installed directory --> then bin --> run cqlsh from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the page before, but it doesn't have DevCenter available on the page. It has DataStax Enterprise, OpsCenter, Studio, and JavaDriver. Do you know which one would be the correct one?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, I just downloaded DevCenter using the first link you provided, and uncompressed in my computer. A folder with name DevCenter has been created, and there are four elements in that folder: CHANGELOG.md, DevCenter, examples (a folder) and README.md. I assume it's the second element with name DevCenter, right? However, there is no reaction after no matter how I click it. Do you know if I did something wrong?

Comment: It suddenly worked! I am able to open the DevCenter now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A valid account needs to be created before you can download any artifacts from URL mentioned above. Make sure you uncheck to avoid spam from Datastax.

Answer (score 1):

This link should have all the tools and versions.
https://academy.datastax.com/all-downloads

Not sure, why this page has been hidden from Datastax download page.